# Get 500 error on posting Protobuf message to Pulsar schema registry using admin API

Tags: protocol-buffers, http-status-code-500, apache-pulsar

I'm trying to post a Protobuf message to Pulsar schema registry using the Admin [API](https://pulsar.apache.org/admin-rest-api/?version=2.8.0&apiversion=v2#operation/postSchema). But I always receive 500 error. I'm wondering what could be the cause of such behavior. Please, advise.

- URL:

http://localhost:8080/admin/v2/schemas/public/new_ns/new_top/schema

- Payload:

```
    {
       "type": "PROTOBUF", 
       "schema": "syntax = \"proto3\";\n\npackage com.mycorp.mynamespace;\n\nimport 'google/protobuf/any.proto';\n \nmessage SampleRecord { \n\n  int32 my_field1 = 1; \n  double my_field2 = 2; \n  string my_field3 = 3; \n}", 
       "properties": {}
    }
```

- Formatted message definition:

```
    syntax = "proto3";
    
    package com.mycorp.mynamespace;
    
    import 'google/protobuf/any.proto';
     
    message SampleRecord { 
      int32 my_field1 = 1; 
      double my_field2 = 2; 
      string my_field3 = 3; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm entirely unfamiliar with Pulsar but a Googling suggests, you should consider using `"schema": "ProtobufNativeSchema"` from [ComplexType](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/schema-understand/#complex-type) and that the **value** is a Descriptor, i.e.

```sh
protoc \
--include_imports \
--include_source_info \
--proto_path=. \
--descriptor_set_out=sample_record.pb \
./sample_record.proto
```